# Has one association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations, model-associations

I have a User Model with a hasOne relation on Role Model

```
User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    //email, password, and other fields, ...
    roleId: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }}, 
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: "Users"
    });
User.hasOne(Role)
```

and a Role Model

```
Role.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }}, 
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: "Roles"
    });
```

When I try to create a new Role with

```
await Role.create(req.body)
```

And the request is

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/role
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{
    "name": "test role"
}
```

I get the error `column "UserId" does not exist`

And the log says is:

```
routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
sql: 'INSERT INTO "Roles" ("id","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING "id","name","UserId";',
parameters: [
  'test role'
]
```

What did I do wrong here? My table only has `roleId` in the `Users` table, where did the `UserId` in `Roles` table come from?

**Migrations**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Roles', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Roles');
  }
};


'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      // other fields   
      roleId: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          references: {
              model: "Roles",
              key: "id"
          }
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

If I add `Role.belongsTo(User)` in the Role Model, I get the error:

```
models init error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

For the role to be stored in the user table as your schema suggests: `User.belongsTo(Role)` will setup the mapping for you as `RoleId`.

The Model sets up the foreign key the opposite way to the migrations, so results in a missing `UserID` column.

The foreign keys don't need to be defined in the schema unless you want to customise the fields. The `belongsTo`/`hasOne` options are then defined on association call.

```js
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:')

class User extends Model {}
class Role extends Model {}

User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }}, 
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: "Users"
    });

Role.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }}, 
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: "Roles"
    });

User.belongsTo(Role, { foreignKey: 'roleId' })
```

Then you can do things with the association

```js
async function go(){
  await sequelize.sync()
  const role = await Role.create({ name: 'atester' })
  const user = await User.create({ name: 'test' })
  await user.setRole(role)
  
  console.log("%j", await User.findAll({ include: Role }))
}

go().catch(console.error)
```

Results in a document like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "createdAt": "2020-12-04T09:44:05.762Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T09:44:05.763Z",
  "roleId": 1,
  "Role": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "atester",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-04T09:44:05.758Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T09:44:05.758Z"
  }
}
```

From there you can match your migration to the database.

Comment: When creating association and trying something like `user.setRole(role)`, I always get the error `Property 'setRole' does not exist on type 'User'.ts`. I'm using typescript, if that makes any difference.